# Setting the "title" of a UIPopoverController?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uipopovercontroller

I'm sure there's something obvious I'm missing here, but I know that popover controls can have "titles", a header area that has a line of text above the content view (e.g. the "Tools"  popover in iWork).

How can I add this in my own popovers?

Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you're using a UIPopoverController, just make [its `contentViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverController/contentViewController) to be a `UINavigationController`, and set [the `title`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/title) of its deepest view controller.

If you're using a UIActionSheet, it has a [`title` property](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIActionSheet/title) already (which you should notice when initializing with `-initWithTitle:…`.)

Comment: This works, but it seems odd that you have to wrap you UIViewController in a UINavigationController just so the Title property can percolate back up to UIPopoverController.

Answer (score 8):

I have been beating my head against the wall all day with the same problem and I think I finally have the solution :D  You need to use a UINavigationController for the popover's contentViewController, and then add a title to the navigations controller's navigation bar, like you normally would.  Oddly, this doesn't work if you add a navigation bar to your existing view controller.