# UINavigationController in UIPopoverController: setting the title

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to display a `UINavigationController` inside a `UIPopoverController`, but for some reason I can't set the title.

```
SearchViewController *searchView = [[[SearchViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:searchView];
[popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:_searchBarButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

I tried changing it in the `- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil`

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {
    // Change the title
    UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
    label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.text = @"Print / Email";
    [label sizeToFit];
    self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
}
return self;
}
```

I also tried setting it in the `- (void)viewDidLoad`

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 250.0f);

self.navigationItem.title = @"Print / Email";
self.title = @"Print / Email";
}
```

But in no cases the title is working, am I still doing something wrong?

Comment: try removing the titleview label code from - (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT** Add your SearchViewController controller in UINavigationController ad that in UIPopoverController like this:

```
SearchViewController *searchView = [[[SearchViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:searchView];
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navController];
[popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:_searchBarButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Now in SearchViewController's viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.title = @"Print / Email";
}
```

Refer [setting-the-title-of-a-uipopovercontroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617409/setting-the-title-of-a-uipopovercontroller?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work either, I tried that before, it just remains empty.

Comment: Actually it just doesn't show, when I do `NSLog(@"%@", self.title);` it returns the correct title

Comment: Your updated method works indeed, it just seems like a strange way to do it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try with this way to show popover controller

```
SearchViewController *searchView = [[[SearchViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navCont=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:searchView];
UIPopoverController *popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:navCont];
[popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:_searchBarButton permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Comment: Ny `SearchViewController` is already a `UINavigationController`, so shouldn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
SearchViewController *searchView = [[[SearchViewController alloc] init] autorelease];

UINavigationController *_nav = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRoot.....:searchView] autorelease];
```

then put _nav into the popover.

each UIViewController has its own tabbar and navigation but you should init them.then you can use them rightly.